# Regex : grab a single character in a line without grabbing instances of it in other line

Tags: regex

I'm trying to grab line 2, a single character ; that keeps reoccurring during the generation of one of my config files. It's breaking my builds. I need to replace the ; with an empty character or just remove the line entirely. The issue I'm having is grabbing that character and none of the other ; characters.

```
- HOSTS all
;
jjlkasd;
 - aslkdjasd;
```

Comment: If you are doing it line by line then `^;$` should do it

Comment: If you are doing it over the entire contents of the file then `\n;\n` should work.

Comment: I'm using it with ansible's lineinfile so the first line by line regex worked perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
$ echo "$inp"
- HOSTS all
;
jjlkasd;
 - aslkdjasd;
```

You can use `sed`:

```
$ echo "$inp" | sed 's/^;$//'
- HOSTS all

jjlkasd;
 - aslkdjasd;
```

Or if there is any possibility of leading or trailing spaces:

```
$ echo "$inp" | sed 's/^\s*;\s*$//'
- HOSTS all

jjlkasd;
 - aslkdjasd;
```

Or, if you want to delete the entire line:

```
$ echo "$inp" | sed '/^\s*;\s*$/d'
- HOSTS all
jjlkasd;
 - aslkdjasd;
```